# QGIS LTR versions updates

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

When QGIS is starting, there is a banner announcing that a new version is available but it does not tell about new LTR versions. I'm working with QGIS 2.14.11-Essen LTR and I get that:

[image]

To get new releases informations, it is necessary to check QGIS official website. Is there a way to automatically get informations about releases, either within QGIS or not?

Answer (score 1):

Within QGIS, you may get some informations from `Help` > `Check QGIS Version`:

[image]

Instead, the roadmap for future releases (any kind of release) is always trackable in the [Release Schedule](https://www.qgis.org/it/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule).

Comment: Thanks @HowToInQGIS! But nothing about LTRs with `Check QGIS Version` pop-up...

Comment: I remember there was some info about LTRs, but it is probably changed from recent versions. However, you asked "either within QGIS or not", so my link should help you, or not? ;)

Comment: Yes and no... In fact, by writting *outside QGIS*, I was rather looking for something like '*Hey, here is a new QGIS LTR version available*' either coming through mails or RSS for instance.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I'm sorry, but can't no longer help you, good luck!

Comment: Just checked QGIS official website that does not offer RSS feeds for news. This could have been an option then...

Comment: There is already http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13178 and http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15388 waiting to be implemented ...